# Use the midpoint rule to estimate distance traveled

Tags: calculus

The velocity graph of a car accelerating from rest to a speed of 120 km/h over a period of 30 seconds is shown. Use the Midpoint Rule with n = 6 to estimate the distance (in km) traveled during this period.[image]

I found the midpoints and estimated the points, getting 
(2.5,30),(7.5,65),(12.5,90),(17.5,105),(22.5,115), and(27.5,119)
 
I don't know how to convert from seconds to hours. I know that I can get the answer by multiplying the sum of all the converted y-values by 5, I just need to know how to convert. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are 60 seconds in a minute and 60 minutes in an hour, so there are 60*60=3600 seconds in an hour.  So you can convert from seconds to hours by dividing by 3600.

Comment: I got about .727777... for my final answer. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That doesn't look so bad.  The middling speed of 60 km/hr is 1 km/min, so in 30 seconds you would go 0.5 km.  The fact that the speed curve is above a straight line says you will go farther.